# Ruby && vs and: Why does `if defined? non_existent && non_existent == "test"` - execute?

Tags: ruby

I am a bit confused about a small logic issue where I have, for example, `test_variable` and would like something executed if `test_variable` is defined and has a particular value, for example `go`.

I'm finding that the following always executes no matter what:

```
if defined? test_variable && test_variable == "go"
  puts "executed"
end
```

which is confusing because

```
puts defined? test_variable # nil
puts test_variable == "go" # NameError: undefined local variable...
```

Then, why does combining them return true?

```
puts defined? test_variable && test_variable == "go" # expression
```

where

```
puts defined? test_variable and test_variable == "go" # nil
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's why

```
defined? test_variable # => nil
defined? test_variable && test_variable == "go" # => "expression"
```

`defined?` call acts on not what you think it should act on (it checks if the whole expression is defined). Learn to apply parentheses. This code won't print `"executed"`.

```
if defined?(test_variable) && test_variable == "go"
  puts "executed"
end
```

To the second point of your question:

`and` has lower precedence than `&&`, so

```
defined? test_variable && test_variable == "go" # defined?(test_variable && test_variable == "go")
```

but

```
defined? test_variable and test_variable == "go" # defined?(test_variable) and (test_variable == "go")
```